# Несоответствие типов при работе с ListBox и книгой

Tags: vba

Код ниже сообщает об ошибке "Несоответствие типов" и именно для ячейки книги содержащей текст длиной более 2000 символов. Ошибка проявляется только к конкретному полю содержащему этот большой текст. Если меньше, то все обрабатывает нормально, а остальные значения переносит в ListBox без проблем.

```
Sub CheckFiltrTr()


    Dim SourceTab()

    SourceTab = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempTab").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value

    Dim RowsCount, ColumnsCount

    RowsCount = UBound(SourceTab, 1)
    ColumnsCount = UBound(SourceTab, 2)


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim x As Long, i As Long
    Dim ArrForInsert()
    x = 0
    ReDim ArrForInsert(0 To RowsCount, 0 To 16)
    With MainForm.MainListBox
    For i = 3 To RowsCount
        If SourceTab(i, 2) = "" Then

                     .AddItem ""
                    .List(x, 0) = SourceTab(i, 1)
                    .List(x, 1) = SourceTab(i, 2)
                    .List(x, 2) = SourceTab(i, 3)
                    .List(x, 3) = SourceTab(i, 4)
                    .List(x, 4) = SourceTab(i, 5)
                    .List(x, 5) = SourceTab(i, 6)
                    **.List(x, 6) = SourceTab(i, 7)**
                    .List(x, 7) = SourceTab(i, 8)
                    .List(x, 8) = SourceTab(i, 9)
                    .List(x, 9) = SourceTab(i, 10)
                    .List(x, 10) = SourceTab(i, 11)
                    .List(x, 11) = SourceTab(i, 12)
                    .List(x, 12) = SourceTab(i, 13)
                    .List(x, 13) = SourceTab(i, 14)
                    .List(x, 14) = SourceTab(i, 15)
                    .List(x, 15) = Round(SourceTab(i, 16))

                    x = x + 1
                End If
        Next i
    End With



End Sub
```

Какая проблема может быть?

Comment: А посмотреть типы данных в Watch Window - не судьба?

Comment: Переменная идет String, а внутри текст 2800 символов. Сокращаю текст - работает.

Comment: Вроде как имя String не может превышать 255, а не содержимое. Или придумывать иной процесс забора значения из ячеек листа?

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте усомниться, что Вы могли загрузить `ListBox` этим кодом :)

Дело в том, что `ListBox` имеет баг - в него с помощью `AddItem`нельзя загрузить более 10 столбцов. Т.е. `.AddItem`, потом `.List(x, j)`... `.List(x, 9)` еще запишется, но на следующей строке получим ошибку.

Но этой ошибки не будет, если список заполнить одним махом. С дополнительным массивом решаем две проблемы - обход бага и обход ошибки записи длинного текста (до 32767 символов).

```
Sub test1()
    MainForm.Show
    Call CheckFiltrTr
End Sub

Sub CheckFiltrTr()
    Dim SourceTab(), aList()
    Dim x As Long, n As Long, i As Long

    SourceTab = Worksheets("TempTab").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value

    For i = 3 To UBound(SourceTab)
        If SourceTab(i, 2) = "" Then x = x + 1
    Next i

    If x = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ReDim aList(1 To x, 1 To 16)

    x = 0

    For i = 3 To UBound(SourceTab)
        If SourceTab(i, 2) = "" Then
            x = x + 1
            aList(x, 1) = SourceTab(i, 1)
            aList(x, 2) = SourceTab(i, 2)
            aList(x, 3) = SourceTab(i, 3)
            aList(x, 4) = SourceTab(i, 4)
            aList(x, 5) = SourceTab(i, 5)
            aList(x, 6) = SourceTab(i, 6)
            aList(x, 7) = SourceTab(i, 7)
            aList(x, 8) = SourceTab(i, 8)
            aList(x, 9) = SourceTab(i, 9)
            aList(x, 10) = SourceTab(i, 10)
            aList(x, 11) = SourceTab(i, 11)
            aList(x, 12) = SourceTab(i, 12)
            aList(x, 13) = SourceTab(i, 13)
            aList(x, 14) = SourceTab(i, 14)
            aList(x, 15) = SourceTab(i, 15)
            aList(x, 16) = Round(SourceTab(i, 16))
        End If
    Next i

    MainForm.MainListBox.List = aList
    Call test2
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Dim i As Long

    With MainForm.MainListBox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            Debug.Print Len(.List(i, 6))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Заполнить массив можно в цикле. Будет чуть медленнее, но код короче:

```
    For j = 1 To 15
        aList(x, j) = SourceTab(i, j)
    Next j

    aList(x, 16) = Round(SourceTab(i, 16))
```

Ошибки, неточности кода, размещенного в вопросе.

Неважно, в каком месте объявлена переменная - память под переменую выделяется сразу при запуске процедуры.  Обычно объявления располагают в начале процедуры

Отключение событий и обновления экрана здесь не нужно - нет изменения на листе. А если уж написано, то нужно включить. И если `ScreenUpdating` включается само по завершении процедуры (правильнее - включать принудительно), то  события (`EnableEvents`) останутся отключенными.

Лишняя строка при заполнении `ListBox`

```
.AddItem ""
.List(x, 0) = SourceTab(i, 1)
```

Сначала в `.List(x, 0)` записали пустую строку, потом перезаписали значением из массива.
Правильно:

```
.AddItem SourceTab(i, 1)
```